# C# error CS1061: Type `System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' does not contain a definition for `Length'

Tags: c#, linq, generics, dictionary

I'm programming in C# and I keep getting the error: "error CS1061: Type `System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' does not contain a definition for`Length' and no extension method `Length' of type`System.Collections.Generic.List' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?:

I've added using System.Linq aswell, which was a solution to a number of similar problems however it still doesn't work.

```
 Dictionary<string, int> decryptedPossibilites = new Dictionary<string, int>();
 foreach(KeyValuePair<string, int> entry in decryptedPossibilites){
      int eCount = entry.Key.Split('E').Length - 1;
      eCountList.Add(eCount);
  }

  int temp = 0;

  for (int write = 0; write < eCountList.Length; write++){
      for (int sort = 0; sort < eCountList.Length - 1; sort++){
          if (eCountList[sort] > eCountList[sort + 1]){
              temp = eCountList[sort + 1];
              eCountList[sort + 1] = eCountList[sort];
              eCountList[sort] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

  foreach(int q in eCountList){
        Console.WriteLine(q);
  }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `Length` --> arrays; `Count` --> `List`, `Set`, etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no `Length` property on `List<T>`. Use [`Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx) instead and for other classes that implement `ICollection`.

`Length` is typically only for arrays.

Comment: Ahh it was so easy! Thanks so much!